# How to align text in a header of QTableView in Qt using only CSS?

Tags: qt, qtableview, qtstylesheets, qheaderview, wincc-oa

I tried the CSS code:

```
QTableView QHeaderView::section {
    text-align: center;
 }
```

And it did not help me.

PS I write the SCADA system in the WinCC OA that uses Qt, and there you can change the appearance of components only using CSS

Comment: table header is used as thead, so you can write thead tr th {text-align: center;}

Comment: @Sonia, it is not HTML, it is Qt and its graphic objects. So there are other CSS selectors here.

Comment: @MaxLich, QSS to be precise. [Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) you can see what is available for each class.

Comment: @scopchanov Thank you, but I have already seen it

Answer (score 4):

As seen in the source code for [`QHeaderView::paintSection`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qheaderview.cpp.html#_ZNK11QHeaderView12paintSectionEP8QPainterRK5QRecti)

```
QVariant textAlignment = d->model->headerData(logicalIndex, d->orientation,
                                              Qt::TextAlignmentRole);
opt.rect = rect;
opt.section = logicalIndex;
opt.state |= state;
opt.textAlignment = Qt::Alignment(textAlignment.isValid()
                                  ? Qt::Alignment(textAlignment.toInt())
                                  : d->defaultAlignment);
```

`QHeaderView` does not uses the stylesheet to define the text alignment, only values from the [`defaultAlignment`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#defaultAlignment-prop) or the data from the header's model (`Qt::TextAlignmentRole`).

Now, if your default alignment is either `Qt::AlignLeft` or `Qt::AlignRight`, you can use the section padding to automatically center it:

```
QTableView QHeaderView::section {
    padding-left: auto;
    padding-right: auto;
}
```

The opposite is not true: if default alignment is center, other calculus affect how padding is used and cannot be used to automatically left- or right-align text.

Answer (score 3):

I have found one of the solutions:

```
QHeaderView {
    qproperty-defaultAlignment: AlignHCenter AlignVCenter;
}
```

Although it works in WinCC OA only partially.

Comment: Interesting access to properties from within the stylesheet, didn't know about it!